# Find the average rate of change of the function over the given interval

Tags: calculus

> $$R(\theta)=\sqrt{4\theta + 1};\theta\in[2,6]$$
>   What is $\frac{\Delta R}{\Delta\theta}$? (Simplify your answer.)

I've watched many videos about finding rate of change, but there are few of them. Should I use this, which gives 4:
$$\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$$
or should I use this, which gives $\sqrt{21}$?
$$\frac{f(x_1 + h) - f(x_1)}h,h=4$$

Comment: If you take $x_1=2$ and $h=4$, you should arrive at the exact same expression no matter which approach you use.

Comment: You should in both cases arrive at the answer $1/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R(\theta)$ is a continuous, positive, increasing function over the interval $[2,6]$.
 Since the *rate of change* of $R$ is locally given by $R'(\theta)$, the *average rate of change* is given by
$$ \frac{1}{4}\int_{2}^{6}R'(\theta)\,d\theta = \frac{R(6)-R(2)}{4} = \frac{5-3}{4}=\color{green}{\frac{1}{2}}$$
by the fundamental theorem of Calculus.
Obviously, if we slightly change the meaning of *average* we get a different result.
For instance, the "*quadratic average rate of change*" is given by
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}\int_{2}^{6}R'(\theta)^2\,d\theta} = \color{red}{\sqrt{\frac{\log 5-\log 3}{2}}}>\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Is "*quadratic average rate of change* " the correct words order? I would benefit from the opinion of a native English speaker, thanks in advance :D

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful answer.! @Jack D`Aurizio